# Schedule the arrival of resources (ex. trucks) in Anylogic

Tags: simulation, anylogic, agent-based-modeling

I have a rackPick block where I am using Trucks as resources to pickup the agents. Is there any way to schedule the arrival of those resources? I want 2 trucks to arrive in a day. I didn't find any property in rackPick or resource Pool regarding scheduling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply define your ResourcePool capacity to be driven "by schedule". Then, define a schedule to define your resources schedule:
[image]

There are several example models showing you how to do it, just search for "schedule" in the example models. And check the help, you can make this combination very powerful :)